# Numpy where ValueError - operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (x, y, z)

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to make the alpha channel in a PNG a particular value, based upon its RGB values. For simplicity, assume I just want to average the first 3 values of each pixel and then change the alpha value based on that.

```
import numpy as np
# both image and avg are a (10, 10, 4)
img = np.random.rand(10, 10, 4)
avg = np.average(img[:, :, :-1], axis=2)
# the mask is a (10, 10)
mask = avg > .5
# np.full((img.shape[0], img.shape[1], 1), 255) creates a (10, 10, 1) array full of the value 255
# np.append(..., axis=2) appends the above so that each pixel will have a 255 at the end
# np.where(mask, ..., img) should use the mask to find each pixel, update that pixel to either use the alpha channel, if true, or keep its alpha channel, if false.  
np.where(mask, np.append(img[:, :, :-1], np.full((img.shape[0], img.shape[1], 1), 255), axis=2), img)
```

Currently (and correctly), it throws the error -> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (10,10) (10,10,4) (10,10,4).

If I had to try to explain it, it's because the mask is a 10 x 10, and the values to act upon are a 10x10x4. So is there a way to "get around this"; to have the true or false values return a pixel with the proper value?

I know I can do this with loops, but I wanted to use numpy natively where I could.

Thanks, all!

Comment: use `mask[...,None]`, to make it (10,10,1)

Comment: `img[mask, -1] = 255`?

Comment: This question was closed 7 hours after this comment. My concerns is that the linked stack overflow post does not answer this question. It is the same error. I understand the error. I was not looking for why the error was being thrown, rather the python / numpy - thonic way of achieving my goal, in light of the error, "without the use of a loop" (not under the hood loop, obviously there is a need for a loop here). I think changing the question title could be potentially helpful. Thoughts from anyone in the community for how to reopen this question or how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `mask` variable does not have the same dimension as your `img` variable, as you mention. There are multiply ways to circumvent this, but I recommend @bb1's suggestion to simplify your code. Replace your last line with

```
img[mask, -1] = 255
```

Basically, it modifies the last channel (alpha channel) of the pixels that satisfy your mask (mask=True) to `255`. Otherwise, the existing alpha value is kept.